# Duplicate fields in a table, distinct doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, distinct-values

I have the following query:

```
select distinct 
  ROW_ID = row_number() over (
    order by wms_us.wms_us.rrno.rrdate
     , wms_us.wms_us.rrno.pono
     , wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.meidhex
     , att.Date_cleared
    )
 , ATT_PO = wms_us.wms_us.rrno.pono
 , Received_Date = wms_us.wms_us.rrno.rrdate
 , IMEI = case
        when len(wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.meidhex) >= 15
        then left(wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.meidhex, 14)
        else wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.meidhex
        end
 , Model = case
        when (wms_us.wms_us.model.modeldesc = 'MIXED')
        then wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.basemodel
        else wms_us.wms_us.model.modelbase
        end
 , Date_cleared = case
        when (Future.[Error Code] = '1')
        then Future.LocalTime
        else att.Date_cleared
        end
 , Result = case
        when (Future.[Error Code] = '1')
        then 'PASS'
        else att.Result
        end
from wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdoc
  inner join wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet
    on wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdoc.transferboxdocid 
      = wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.transferboxdocid
  inner join wms_us.wms_us.rrno
    on wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.rrnoid = wms_us.wms_us.rrno.rrnoid
  inner join wms_us.wms_us.model
    on wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdoc.modelid = wms_us.wms_us.model.modelid
  left join DRSCSQLQADB01.att_view2.dbo.attview2 as att
    on att.IMEI = LEFT(wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.meidhex, 14)
  inner join Futerdial.dbo.Futuredial_Validation as Future
      on Future.IMEI = wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.meidhex
where (wms_us.wms_us.rrno.rrdate > '2016-12-01') 
  and Future.IMEI = '352130070643357'
```

I have the IMEI in the table Futuredial_Validation duplicate, I have been trying to use the Distinct just to show me one IMEI but it's not working, there is any alternative that I can use?? Or I am using it wrong?
Attach a picture of what is showing me, I just one be able to see one the first one.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2NdL.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For rows to be filtered out by distinct, all values must be the same.  In this query it looks like you can just wrap the query in a CTE and filter on ROW_ID = 1.